# intellij static web tomcat configuration

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea, configuration

I have a little problem...

i create new project in intellij for static web

and craete html like image.

[image]

and configuration tomcat, artifact. tomcat running well, but server cannot find index.html.

when i start tomcat, url is http://localhost:port

even i write http://localhost:port/index.html it's response same 404 not found..

one reason i doubt is that there is no add to facets.

[image]

how can i see index.html?

some one help me..

Comment: You need to configure artifacts, etc. Static web project is not designed to be used with Tomcat. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-java-ee-application.html

Comment: thx for comment.